# Finder search differentiates between files of kind CSS and Cascading Style Sheets

Tags: finder, search

when I do a search for files of kind CSS I get 2 results when I should have many but if I search for files of kind Cascading Style Sheet, I get all the results except the other 2...

What's going on here?? I only noticed this after I changed the default app for opening these files...

Comment: I noticed the same thing on my Mac, but I don't know what causes it. You might just use `name:.css` though.

Comment: @LauriRanta thanks for the suggestion I'll use that for now!